# Can't transfer ETH from swap smart contract to user

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I try to send back ether when user sell token in swap, and i have that error:

My solidity pragma: **pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;**

```
project:/contracts/ANQSwap.sol:33:9: ParserError: Expected primary expression.
        payable(address(msg.sender)).transfer(etherToSendBack);
```

It's my function code:

```
    function sellTokens(uint256 _value) public {
        require(anteqToken.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _value, "You doesn't have enought AnteqToken.");
        uint256 etherToSendBack = _value/rate;
        require(address(this).balance >= etherToSendBack, "AnteqToken Swap doesn't have enought Ether to buy yours token.");
        anteqToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _value);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(etherToSendBack);
    }
```

And I too try

```
 payable(address(msg.sender)).transfer(etherToSendBack);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed error

I added one pragma version to all .sol file

**pragma solidity ^0.8.0**

```
payable(msg.sender).transfer(etherToSendBack);
```

Code above works.

I leave this question for other dev if they encountern on similar problem.